# Cannot install PostgreSQL 9.3 (ODOO 8.0-20160420) with exe

Tags: postgresql, odoo

[ODOO exe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG3o0.png)

Cannot install postgreSQL 9.3 that comes with ODOOv8 after uninstalling them both

Comment: i used revo uninstaller to remove ODOO + PostgreSQL - now i cannot install them both again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PROBLEM SOLVED

Technical note: after investigation it seems that the PostgreSQL 9.x uninstaller does not cleanup the registry keys in the same fashion as the 8.3 did, and the following keys remain after a complete uninstall:

```
HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL +- HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL\Installations +- HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL\Services
```

Currently our installer just checks for the presence of the HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL entry, but it could still be there even if no PostgreSQL installation remains. So when it is present we should verify that at least one entry exists under HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL\Installations. The 8.3 installer apparently removed the PostgreSQL entry altogether, so that should work everywhere.

PS: when manually using regedit on a x64 system these keys will be found under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node, which is the "reflection key" that is mapped to HKLM\Software for 32bits processes running on a 64bits machine. It can be ignored for all purposes except when manually viewing/editing the registry. The installer will run as 32bits so it will find them in the normal location.